# How do I access Next.js context data in _app when rendering server side (without getInitialProps)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am removing `getInitialProps` from the `_app.js` file and need to be able to get the user's `accept-language` either when rendering server-side or client-side. In order to do that I need to have access to the Next.js context in the _app component. How can I get access to that?

```js
const getAcceptLanguageString = (): string => {
  let req: IncomingMessage | undefined;
  if (!isClientSide()) {
    return req?.headers['accept-language'] ?? 'en-US';
  }
  return window.__NEXT_DATA__?.props?.acceptLanguage ?? '';
};

const MyApp = ({
  Component,
  apolloClient,
  router,
}) => {
  const acceptLanguage = getAcceptLanguageString();
  // Do something with `acceptLanguage`

  return <Component />;
};
```

Comment: If you're removing `getInitialProps` from `_app` and want to access data from the `req` object then you'll have to do it inside your pages' `getServerSideProps`. Out of curiosity, what are you doing with the `Accept-Language` value?

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves! We're using it to initialize our i18n localization.

Comment: Are you using Next.js [i18n routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)? That provides automatic locale detection based on the `Accept-Language` header by default.